# PHP vs ASP.NET static variables

Tags: php, asp.net, static

Static variables in ASP.NET caught me off guard today.  Then i became freaked out, because this means either i have a fundamental misunderstanding of static variables in the world of the web or ASP.NET does not act like i thought it would.

So in ASP.NET

```
public class MyClass {
    public static bool myVar = true;    
}
```

If ASPUserA sets `MyClass.myVar = false` every other user on the system would experience these changes.  So, ASPUserB would have `myVar` = `false`.  My Source:     http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/avoid-static-variables-in-asp-net/

```
class MyClassPHP {
    public static $myVar = false;
}
```

If PHPUserA sets `MyClass::$myVar = true` does this mean that every user on the system experiences these changes???

Thank you.

---

Upon further research i did this;

```
class MyClassPHP {
    public static $myVar = 0;
}
```

Then i had users who went to a page do this

```
MyClassPHP::$myVar++;
echo MyClassPHP::$myVar;
```

It always was 1.  No matter how many times i refreshed or simultaneous connections... WOHHH that was a great conclusion, or else i am screwed!!

---

ASP.NET update

Upon further research and testing things i found this.

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static int myInt = 0;

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        myInt++;
    }

}
```

Then my page can display `myInt`.

Between the browsers (Firefox and chrome) the `myInt` was progressively higher as i refreshed the page.  So this does not matter if your `class` is `static`.  It only matters if you have static variables.  They are application wide.

Comment: WOW!  Does ASP.NET really do that?  That's stupid =/

Comment: I am so confused by it.  It kind of blew my Paradigms out a window!

Comment: Thanks for convincing me *never* to use ASP.NET ;-P

Comment: can you explain why is myVar static here if its changing across every request?

Comment: @Baz1nga: Because in PHP once the request is done, the script is done, and PHP is no longer running.

Comment: @Baz1nga  I updated the code to show you how it would work in ASP.NET

Comment: It is still possible to have per-instance (session) variables in ASP.NET, but it is also possible to have a shared variable across sessions. Is it possible to have a shared variable or class across all users in PHP? If so, then this is more of a terminology issue than anything.

Comment: @ctc i have never seen anything that can be shared like that.  If so, then it truely is a terminology issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When running in IIS:

A static variable is not "page" specific. It is "AppDomain" specific. The only relation to the "page" would be the path (so to speak) of the variable (MyProject.MyPage.MyVariable for example). Because all users of your application are running in the same AppDomain (i.e. same IIS application folder), then they will all use the same static variable. So... eventually your users are going to see each each other's information since they are all sharing that one single static variable.

PHP however tracks statics PER USER INSTANCE, so I guess you could call them "safer from the singleton dangerzone".

Comment: I mean its not... horrible? You have to get around it in some instances, but in others its AWESOME when it comes to memory management. Then you can have a single object operating the same function across a group of users instead of having 10 copies of the same object doing the same thing. I guess its just a matter of preference :D

Comment: This is old, but this is not a matter of preference, a page is accesed by more than one user, so, the normal behaivor would be the PHP's one, not ASP.Net... this is not a Windows Form that is single user... it really explodes your paradigms like singleton to manage database but with different connection queries... one user enters one page, has A connection, changes to other page has B connection, but a new user go to C, and he sees A or B until it is changed... really frustrating to not be able to use singleton PER USER...

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP isn't as stupid as ASP.NET (does it seriously do that?).  Static variables in PHP are per instance (it's not like ASP.NET where the whole page is one instance, each user gets their own PHP instance).

If 2 users go to a PHP page, and on one page `MyClass::$myVar = true` is ran, it doesn't affect the other user.

Comment: why this is stupid ? Static is not session variables. From what you say the static on php pages are connected to the user, and how that can be ? If the user have no cookie ? then the static is not connected and each time a new static born ? I think that MS done a great job, static is what is say for the pool.

Comment: asp.net user Session variables that do what you say. From the other hand how php keep common data across all running instances ? For example I use the static to declare something that is not change and used a lot on all users, how you do that on php ?

Comment: @Aristos: "declare something that is not change and used a lot on all users"  You don't, or you store it in a database.

Comment: @Aristos: "Static is not session variables" Yes.  Sessions exist through different requests, static variables don't.  When the script is done, PHP exits, and all variables are garbage collected (except cookie/session).

Comment: So I understand that static work the same on php and asp.net, the different is that asp.net keep live the pool that running the request VS php that is not keep it running, but start it and end it per request.

Comment: @Aristos: Also in ASP.net static variables are the same for *all* users.  In PHP, each user has their own copy.

Comment: Is not 100% correct the last one. The static variables are the same per pool. All users not see the same variables, see the same variables that exist on the same pool. Do not count to move data from user to user with static.

Comment: It is really dumb to save a static variable to all the users... in a web page EVERY user is "new", so why hold a static in him... why share it ? Every new user has his things about DB, Sessions, etc... ASP is garbage in this things... All ASP handles should be like PHP, PER USER, PER REQUEST, not like a windows form in the background, it is really annoying and frustrating...